# Why requestAnimFrame need bind(this)

Tags: javascript, prototype, bind, requestanimationframe

Why does `window.requestAnimFrame` must be called like this: `window.requestAnimFrame(this.__proto__.animate.bind(this));` and not like `window.requestAnimFrame(this.__proto__.animate);`.

My js-class looks like:

```
Game = function (moduleConfig, gameConfig) {
    this.moduleConfig = moduleConfig;
    this.gameConfig = gameConfig;

    // Game-Commands
    this.keyCommands = {
        moveLeft: false,
        moveRight: false
    };

    // Some init stuff

    requestAnimFrame(this.animate.bind(this));


    return this;
}

/**
 * Init the game system
 * @param {moduleConfig} moduleCongif - Module-Config instance
 */
Game.prototype = {

    // General member
    self: null,
    moduleConfig: null,
    gameConfig: null,

    // Game member
    renderer: null,
    catcher: null,
    stage: null,

    // Nested 'static' objects
    keyCommands: {
        moveLeft: false,
        moveRight: false
    },


    // Some more stuff

    /**
     * Main loop
     */
    animate: function () {
        window.requestAnimFrame(this.__proto__.animate.bind(this));

        // Some more things to do
    }
}
```

If i do not use `bind`, i get the following error message: `Failed to execute 'requestAnimationFrame' on 'Window': The callback provided as parameter 1 is not a function.`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your animate is Game's method and since its a recursive function it need a context to be able to call the next animate.

Now i've already told you that(or maybe it was someone) else but .bind is really bad to use for many reason - for you the main reason its extremely slow and you are making a render functionality that need to run extremely fast

to avoid the use of bind i would do:

```
animate: function () {
    var self = this
    window.requestAnimFrame(function(){
        self.animate();
    });

    // Some more things to do
}
```

Comment: Okay, now i understand the context changing in recursive functions. That was my problem.

Answer (score 1):

window.requestAnimFrame may call the window.requestAnimationFrame which will call the parameter function every second.Without 'bind(this)','this.**proto**.animate' will call window.**proto**.animate.With 'bind(this)',it will call the Game's animate function and that will be correct.'bind(this)' just pass the Game context to this.